# How can I achieve staggered_grid_view's StaggeredTile.fit in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, staggered-gridview

I would like to achieve a grid view with variable height.
Also, its view should be adjusted to match the height of the image.
So, I thought this Package is very good to achieve the feature. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

However, I get an error with the following code.

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      body: const ContentsMixView(),
    );
  }
}

class ContentsMixView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ContentsMixView({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
      itemCount: 15,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network('https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51ZxU6FYLuL._SX315_BO1,204,203,200_.jpg'),
              Text('hello'),
              Text('\$100'),
              Text('_location'),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
      staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    );
  }
}
```

The error message is as follows.

```
Updated layout information required for RenderIndexedSemantics#80e91 NEEDS-LAYOUT to calculate semantics.
'package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2647 pos 12: '!_needsLayout'
```

I tried to surround StaggeredGridView.countBuilder with Expanded Widget. But I couldn't.
Please tell me how to turn off this error.

Comment: I've ran through the code, also put your `StaggeredGridView` within an `Expanded` inside a `Column` widget but no error show up still. Can you recheck if this is the code that cause the error?

Comment: @Bach The problem is, the plugin is inheriting the layout size from the child to create the staggered tiles, but in my case, the child changes dimension for every network loaded image. So, I think this problem cause is `Image.network`.
This plugin would be problematic for every new addition of a network image because it has to redraw the layout.
I went to the plugin's github page and tried to run example_8 (the gif image sample in pub.dev) in my environment, but I got the same error.